# How do I use VBA to append an ID number to the end of each row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with about 3450 items on it. I use a pivot table to show a chart of this information using a filter. The problem is that there are duplicate values in the 'results' section. I want these to be included in the chart so I need to apply an ID to each row. Is there a script to add a sequential number (1,2,3,...) to column O?

Comment: Put "1" on `O1`, then "2" on `O2` then highlight both cells and drag down to row 3450. Excel will autoincrement the number. You can also use the formula `=Row()` to populate the cell with the row number. VBA would be overkill I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is set to work on Sheet number 1, you can change that to whichever sheet you need it on.  It also starts on row one for column O.

```
Sub Add_to_O()
LRow = Sheets(1).Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 1 to LRow
  Sheets(1).Range("O" & I).value = Sheets(1).Range("O" & I).value & I
Next I
End Sub
```